# Find all TIME fields between 15-29 minutes with hour related to timezone

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When saving `TIME` values into the MySQL database, our server automatically converts these dates to be formatted in UTC time, because of this we've stored our user's timezone offset in our database. Considering we had a simple database like composed of three fields, how would we go about getting the time within the allotted minute range with the appropriate hour.

```
id | offset | alertTime
---|--------|----------
 1 | 360    | 4:22:38
 2 | 420    | 3:28:41
```

In this table, user 1 has a 6 hour offset (CST) and user 2 has a 5 hours offset and a 7 hour offset (MDT) I need to find both of these user's (and any other users) that are all within the same hour after timezone calculation.

The conversion to these user's time is nearly the same, both users have an alert scheduled for 10PM 22Minuts nad 10PM 28 minutes, although different times are entered into the database due to UTC conversion.

Let's say I wanted to get all users who have an alert set for 10PM, between 10:16 and 10:29 CST regardless of their timezone.

Just to clarify, user's who set their alertTime in their own timezone, should be returned if their timezone converts to 10:16 - 10:29 CST.  So, 9:16-9:29 MDT would also be returned in these results.

Hope that wasn't too confusing.

--

I'm using MariaDB through NodeJS if that matters.

Answer (score -1):

Don't store them into a `TIMESTAMP` column; store them as `DATETIME`.  That way, there is no offset during the insert, nor the select.

If you also need UTC, maybe you need two columns, one of each type?

Comment: DATETIME stores the date, which is unecessary. I need the TIME only, as this alert should be sent once a day. (Think of an alarm). The offset is necessary, as the server will not always be at the same timezone as the user.

Comment: If you are doing the "alarm" with an `EVENT`, none of that matters.

Comment: Could you please be elaborate on the event? Times are stored on the server in 15 minute intervals, I have a NodeJS backend that executes a query every 15 minutes.

Comment: `EVENT` is a feature of MySQL.  It will perform a specified operation repeated, according to a user-specified pattern, such as every 15 minutes.

Comment: I will look into it, Also I'm using a `TIME` column, not a `TIMESTAMP` unless it's just an alias. Thanks

Comment: `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` are very different.  Study further.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the question before making an answer, as it clearly states what I'm using. It also clearly states my use case.